# How can I pass props and state interface to a React class if I extend a custom class?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

this is how react class is being implemented in typescript:

```
export class Signup extends Component<SignupProps, SignupState> {}

interface SignupProps {
  onSignup: (e: FormEvent, state: SignupState) => void;
}
interface SignupState {
  data: {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    name: string;
  };
}
```

Since i have signup and login forms, to prevent the duplicating of code, I created a BaseForm class, and i place all the reusable logic in there and inheriting from there now.

```
   export class Signupextends BaseForm {}
```

However I am having issue with props and i dont know how to pass the props and state interface.

```
export class Signup<SignupProps, SignupState> extends BaseForm {}
```

in this case, I get `onSignup` props warning but I did not get this warning when I was extenting `React.Component`

"Property 'onSignup' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode;"

```
  export class Signup extends BaseForm<SignupProps, SignupState> {}
```

in this case it says: "Type 'BaseForm' is not generic."

i tried both methods but both did not work. I cannot see what would be the third option.

Comment: Can you also include the definition of the props and state?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, You are trying to pass Props and State types to class which is not extended from React Component.

Try next code, this should work for You

```js
class BaseForm<P,S> extends React.Component<P,S> {}

class SIgnup extends BaseForm<Props, State> {}
```

However, I'd like to recommend to use function composition, higher order components, higher order function or render props pattern to make your logic reusable.

Here You can find [more patterns](https://reactpatterns.com/#render-prop)

Please take a look here:

```js
type Props = {
  // make proper types for args, don't use any
  children:(...args: any[])=>React.ReactNode
}

class BaseForm extends Component<Props,State> {  
   handleFoo=()=>{}
   handleBar=()=>{}
   
   render(){
     this.props.children({handleFoo: this.handleFoo, handleBar: this.handleBar})
   }
}

class Signup extends from React.Component {
  render(){
   <BaseForm>{
     ({handleFoo, handleBar})=><div>42</div>
   }</BaseForm>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Signup extends BaseForm {}
```

this is BaseForm:

```
export abstract class BaseForm extends React.Component<
  SignupProps,
  SignupState
> {}
```

this works. While i do research, I finally learnt why abstract class is handy. Inheritance is very good case to use abstract class. Becase this BaseForm class is not going to be instantiated, and since LoginForm and SignUpForm are going to have doSubmit() method and schema property i set a default value in Base class:

```
abstract schema: {} = {};
  //   defining doSubmit:(e:FormEvent):void was not accepted ???
abstract doSubmit(e: FormEvent): void;
```

then in SignUpForm implemented them as follow:

```
schema = {
    name: Joi.string().alphanum().min(5).required().label("Name"),
    password: Joi.string().min(5).max(15).required().label("Password"),
    email: Joi.string().email(),
  };
  doSubmit(e: FormEvent) {
    this.props.onSignup(e, this.state);
  }
```

since i will be using this baseclass in LoginForm and SignUpForm this is how I defined interface:

```
interface SignupProps {
  onSignup?: (e: FormEvent, state: SignupState) => void;
  onLogin?: (e: FormEvent, state: SignupState) => void;
}
```